# Undefined variable $email when sending mail - even though the variable exists?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an array of emails I need to send a message to in Laravel 4.2. This array is

```
$email_arr = ["me@yahoo.com","friend@gmail.com"]
```

Now my logic is to simply iterate through the email array and send a message to each one, like so:

```
foreach($email_arr as $email){
            Mail::send('emails.invite', array('pool_code' => 'test'), function($message) {
                $message->to($email)->subject('Join my capture pool!');
            });
        }
```

However, I get an error pointing to `$message->to($email)->subject('Join my capture pool!');` which says `Undefined variable: email`.

I find this strange as the variable clearly exists, and if I `echo $email` within the loop it prints out each email correctly.

So what's happening here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (a.k.a closure), which dosen't have `$email` in its scope.

> Closures (anonymous functions) may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

You have to add `use` to this function.

```
foreach($email_arr as $email){
    Mail::send('emails.invite', array('pool_code' => 'test'), function($message) use($email) {
        $message->to($email)->subject('Join my capture pool!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Yup, that does it. Thanks. Will accept the answer in 10 minutes.